# Trace and linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace

I was studying linear functionals and came across this question.

Suppose that for a given matrix $B$ in $M_n$, the linear space of $n\times n$ real matrices, a function $f_B:M_n\to \mathbb R$ is defined through 
$$f_B(A)=\mbox{trace}(B^t A)$$

Show:

1. $f_B$ is a linear functional.
2. Every linear functional is of the form $f_B$ for some $B$.

Comment: I was able to get $\sum b_ii a_ii$, is this enough to show that its a linear functional ?

Comment: That's not correct. ${\rm Tr}(B^TA) = \sum_i \sum_j b_{ij}a_{ij}$. Then yes, it is linear in $A$ because it is (manifestly) linear in each element.

Answer (score 3):

For 1, use the properties of the trace to prove that 
$$
f_B(c_1 A_1 + c_2 A_2) = c_1 f_b(A_1) + c_2 f_b(A_2)
$$
For 2, note that the space of linear functionals over the $n^2$ dimensional space $M_n$ is $n^2$.  Then, it suffices to find $n^2$ linearly independent functionals of the form $f_B$.